# C - Function parameter as case in switch statement

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

The title was a little too vague for google.

I found myself planning to write this switch statement multiple times so I wanted to move it into a function.

What I'm looking to do is create a function that takes a value, what you expect the value to be, and a string identifier for the value.

```
bool checkValue(int value, uint8_t expected, char * id) {
    switch (value) {
        case expected:
            return true;
        case -1:
            printf("Error: Timeout on %s\r\n", id);
        default:
            printf("Error: %s=%02x\r\n", id, value);
            return false;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that the "expression must have a constant value" on the `case expected:` line. Now, I know I could change this to a series of `if`s but I'm interested in why this is doesn't work, or if there is a way to make it work.

Are switch statements just compiled in a way that makes it impossible to substitute a variable into a case value?

Comment: Yes, the case label must be constant expression.

Comment: You can't use variables in case expressions! it has to be constant!

Comment: It doesn't work because the spec doesn't allow it.

Comment: And the spec does not allow it because it wants to permit case statements to be compiled into more efficient implementations than a series of conditional branches.  A single branch based on a jump table, for example.  (Whether a particular compiler in fact chooses to do that is an altogether different question.)

Comment: ... Not to overlook the added fun of what to do when `expected == -1`.

Comment: @Jongware do you mean **what** the compiler is **to do** in that situation? Or is there an issue in my code such that if `value==-1` and `expected=0xff` I would get a match?

Comment: @user3817250: You don't have a `break` on case -1, so after it prints the timeout message, it will "fall through" to the default case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error pretty much tells you why it's forbidden. It's covered in 6.4.2 [stmt.switch]:

> 2 The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a
>   class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to
>   integral or enumeration type exists (12.3). [...] Any statement within
>   the switch statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as
>   follows:
>
> `case constant-expression :`
>
> where the *constant-expression* shall be a converted constant expression
>   (5.19) of the promoted type of the switch condition. No two of the
>   case constants in the same switch shall have the same value after
>   conversion to the promoted type of the switch condition.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that.  A `switch` statement requires that all the `case` values be explicit constant expressions — intuitively, expressions whose value can be determined just by looking at them.

This is actually a feature: when I see a `switch`, I immediately know that the flow of control is not going to depend on runtime values.  If the values change at runtime, a different idiom is used, the *continued conditional*:

```
if(value == expected) {
    return true;
} else if(value == -1) {
    printf("Error: Timeout on %s\r\n", id);
    return false;
} else {
    printf("Error: %s=%02x\r\n", id, value);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a requirement by C. `value` has to be constant. Just change the `case` into an     `if-elseif-else` statement.